# PDFs filled with itext5 are not working with read out loud in Adobe Reader

Tags: java, pdf, itext

We are using itext5 library to fill a PDF with data. The generated PDFs are not AODA compliance. If I save the generated PDF and try to read it loud with Adobe Reader, its only reading few words here and there. Is anybody now the solutions in itext for this issue. We are using PDFStamper and PDFCopy classes from itext. Here is the piece of code:

```
public PDFPopulator(byte[] pdfTemplate, ReportOptions options, OutputStream resultPdf) throws Exception {
        originalPdfTemplate = pdfTemplate;
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
        reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();
        pdfTemplate = applyOptions(pdfTemplate, options);
        document = new Document(reader.getPageSizeWithRotation(1));
        // If we used PdfSmartCopy the result PDF would be significantly smaller (15Mb VS 260Mb),
        // but the memory consumption would be slightly bigger (10-15 times) and the execution time longer (5%). 
        // Personally, I would use PdfSmartCopy over PdfCopy and have a smaller PDF, especially as we going 
        // to put the report generation in a queue.
        writer = new PdfSmartCopy(document, resultPdf);
        writer.setFullCompression();
        writer.setPdfVersion(PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7);
        writer.setCloseStream(false);
        document.open();

        this.pdfTemplate = pdfTemplate;
    }

public void populate(List<FieldContainer> fieldContainers) throws Exception {
        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (FieldContainer fContainer : fieldContainers) {
            byte[] pdfTemplateTemp = fContainer.getOptions() != null 
                    ? applyOptions(originalPdfTemplate, fContainer.getOptions()) 
                    : pdfTemplate;
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplateTemp);
            reader.consolidateNamedDestinations();
            int numPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
            reportCounter++;

            // Fill the form
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
            AcroFields form = stamp.getAcroFields();

            for (String fieldName : form.getFields().keySet()) {
                Object fieldValue = fContainer.getValue(fieldName);
                if (fieldValue != null && !fieldValue.equals("")) {
                    if (fieldName.startsWith("getImage")) {
                        addImage(stamp, form.getFieldItem(fieldName), fieldValue);
                    } else {
                        form.setField(fieldName, fieldValue.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            stamp.setFormFlattening(true);
            stamp.close();

            // Write pages
            PdfReader tempRead = new PdfReader(baos.toByteArray());
            for (int i = 1; i <= numPages; i++) {
                writer.addPage(writer.getImportedPage(tempRead, i));
            }
            writer.freeReader(tempRead);
            writer.freeReader(reader);
            writer.flush();
            baos.close();
            tempRead.close();
            reader.close();
        }
        if(LOGGER.isLoggable(Level.FINE)){
            LOGGER.fine("PDF populated in : " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp) / 1000) + " sec.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you show no code and no sample PDF output, your answer can only be answered in general terms. Which means: The issue is that *you are using* iText in a way that produces PDFs which are not AODA compliant or you have found bugs in Adobe Reader. iText is a general purpose library and, therefore, also allows you to make fun of any read aloud applications.

Comment: HI there.. i am trying to add code here, but i am getting error, that it is too long. Is there any way I can attach the file here.

Comment: I tried adobe reader for other pdfs. It is working fine for all others. As i mentioned above, we use PDFStamper to populate the fields

Comment: PdfStamper stamp = new PdfStamper(reader, baos);
AcroFields form = stamp.getAcroFields();
for (String fieldName : form.getFields().keySet()) {
 Object fieldValue = fContainer.getValue(fieldName);
 if (fieldValue != null && !fieldValue.equals("")) {
  if (fieldName.startsWith("getImage")) {
                addImage(stamp, form.getFieldItem(fieldName), fieldValue);
         } else {
  form.setField(fieldName, fieldValue.toString());
 }
}
}
stamp.setFormFlattening(true);
stamp.close();

Comment: *"i am trying to add code here, but i am getting error, that it is too long"* - Please don't provide such additions in comments but instead [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39757784/edit) your question (there is an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39757784/edit) link just beneath your question). In particular code is very hard to read in comments.

Comment: That been said, I see you use a `PdfStamper`. Thus, you have a source file you manipulate. To reproduce and analyze the issue, therefore, we would need the source PDF. Furthermore please state which exact technical AODA requirement is violated. Adobe Reader not being able to *read aloud* the document might, after all, be merely a bug of the Reader...

Comment: I just google'd around a bit. If http://www.aoda.ca/the-four-levels-of-pdf-accessibility/ applies, sure PDF accessibility for AODA can only be achieved by manual checking and re-tagging of each and every document before publishing.

Comment: I tried Adobe to read the same PDF sample before filling it with itext. readaloud is working fine. Our pdfs are templates and we added fields to it manually.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow. I tried but there is no option to attach a file here.

Comment: *"I tried but there is no option to attach a file here."* - Indeed, there is none (except for some bitmap image formats). If attaching a file is necessary, you usually use a file sharing service (please use something like public shares on dropbox or googledrive, not some service that hides the file among ads).

Comment: here is the drop box link for the file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/w8na34xrmd3pml4/83-0461E-2014-Elem-Public-Gr16.pdf?dl=0

Comment: I'm sorry not to have replied anything here. I have the problems that (a) I cannot run your code as it is - could it be reduced to a simple and runable example? Which e.g. simply sets a specific field to a specific value and the result PDF already is a sample for the issue? (b) I have no specific text-to-speech module installed. Is there an easy way to test without? Or is there a free module which also is easy to install and to uninstall again?